# Within a slider, the active slide fades out, but the next slide doesn't fade in; it just appears.

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel, fadein, fadeout

How can I make the effect smoother so that the next image fades in instead of just appearing? The active slide fades out, and then the next one appears after the first slide fades to white. This doesn't look very smooth or elegant, and I would like to have the fadein/out happen more naturally

The HTML is:

```
<div id="jumbotron"> 
 <div class="slider">

    <img class="img" src="http://photos.travellerspoint.com/203325/Peru_239.jpg" width="100%">

    <img class="img" src="https://kojin.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/sm-08-3281-white-alpaca-pond-white-peaks.jpg" width="100%">
    <img class="img"src="http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get/I0000aT96V0jJZX4/s/650/650/Alpaca-Wool-Factory-El-Alto-Bolivia-17.jpg" width="100%"> 

    <img class="img"src="https://kitaliana.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/rug_cusco1.jpg" width="100%">

</div>
</div>
```

and the JQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.slider'); 
  var $slide = 'img';
  var $transition_time = 2000;
  var $time_between_slides = 4000; 

  function slides(){
    return $slider.find($slide);
  }

  slides().fadeOut();

  // set active classes
  slides().first().addClass('active');
  slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

  // auto scroll 
  $interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually that your images are not stacked on top of each other. When a new image fades in, it does so below (y-axis, not z-axis) the current image and when you remove the old image from the DOM, the new one jumps to its place, making it appear as if it didn't fade in.

Add the following CSS to make sure all images are at the same coordinates, i.e. properly stacked above each other

```
.slider { position:relative;}
.slider > .img { position:absolute;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d62v6fq9/1/ for a complete example based on your code.